# Migrating to Vue 3 but router view is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-i18n

I having a vue 2 project and currently migrating it to vue 3, but the router-view is not able to render the component while the path is correct. I have check on the issue, the problem seem is because of the Vue.extend in vue 2.

Vue component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import AppHelper from 'eb-common/src-base/app.helper'
import { i18n } from '../i18n/login.i18n'
import App from './LoginApp.vue'
import store from './store'
import CONFIG from '../config'

const metainfo = require('../metainfo.json')

const v = Vue.extend({
    i18n,
    store,
    beforeMount() {
        this.setupVue(CONFIG, metainfo, i18n)
    },
    methods: AppHelper.methods,
    beforeUnmount: AppHelper.beforeUnmount,
    components: {
        App
    },
    template: '<App/>'
})

export default v
```

Router config:

```
    import Login from './components/Login/theLogin.routes'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/eb-app-login',
        name: 'eb-app-login',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login-app" */ './login.app'),
        redirect: { path: '/eb-app-login/login/' },
        children: [].concat(Login)
    }
]

export default routes
```

Anyone have any suggestions to make it to work?

I have tried with defineComponent in vue 3, but its not working as well. The code is as below:

```
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

import AppHelper from 'eb-common/src-base/app.helper'
import { i18n } from '../i18n/login.i18n'
import App from './LoginApp.vue'
import store from './store'
import CONFIG from '../config'

const metainfo = require('../metainfo.json')

const v = defineComponent({
  i18n,
  store,
  methods: AppHelper.methods,
  beforeUnmount: AppHelper.beforeUnmount,
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: '<App/>'
})


export default v
```

Comment: Please add to your question more details as to what the exact error or the unexpected behavior is that you're experiencing. "having some issue" and "not really working as well" are vague, unclear statements.   You say you tried using `defineComponent`, please also include that code showing your attempt, it's ok if the code doesn't work. As far as `Vue.extend`, have you read the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-extend-removed) for advice on how to rewrite your component?

Comment: I hv updated the details above. The issue is that it not able to render to component while the path is correct, the router-view is not able to render the component while i trying to import the component that created with Vue.extend.